# Center elements within a view

Tags: css, react-native

I have a form component with some TextInput subcomponents as follows:

```
const FormComponent = () => {
  return (
    <View style={StyleSheet.container}>
      <TextInput1/>
      <TextInput2/>
      <TextInput3/>
    </View>
  )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
  },
});
```

When i try to center align the form components using the StyleSheet, nothing seems to happen. I.e., the text inputs remain at the top left corner of the screen.

However, if I apply the styling directly to the View as follows:

```
<View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: "center", alignItems: "center" }}>
```

then the textinput components become center aligned on the screen.

I dont understand why this is happening and would like to keep the code clean by using stylesheets to do this if possible.

Comment: You are using `StyleSheet.container` instead of `styles.container`. Simple typo :)

Comment: @HaseebA derp. Thanks haha.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use styles instead of StyleSheet , that's a typo**

```
 <View style={styles.container}>
      <TextInput1/>
      <TextInput2/>
      <TextInput3/>
    </View>
```